# react-native-web and react-native-router-flux import issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

When I try to use react-native-web library to create a browser compatible react-native app , if doesn't work if the app contains react-native-router-flux library for routing.

The bundle.js file created by webpack gives the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected token import.

Comment: This sounds like a Babel - are you sure the config you're using to transpile your code is correct?

Answer (score 6):

There are a few issues when using `react-native-router-flux` with `react-native-web`.

### Babel compilation

Most react-native libraries include uncompiled ES6 JS, so you need to tell Babel to compile this Javascript. Babel is ignoring everything in `node_modules` because you have this line in your webpack config: `exclude: /node_modules/`

However, you don't want to remove that line. It's usually a good idea to exclude `node_modules`, because there a lot of other libraries that don't need compilation, so Babel would be doing a lot of unnecessary work.

Instead, you should add this to your webpack config, in the loaders array:

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: /node_modules\/react-native-/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: { cacheDirectory: true }
  },
```

This will tell Babel to compile any libraries that start with `react-native-`.

There were a number of other issues when I wrote this answer, but all of my PRs have been merged, so everything should be working after this.

Comment: This is a *very* thorough answer, and probably should be marked as the solution

Comment: Thanks, I actually just removed a whole lot, because all of the fixes have been merged now.